# selection of drop down item using in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, selenium

I am facing a problem in drop down item selection. Please help me. I have created a function in my user `exensions.js`

```
Selenium.prototype.doDropdown= function(locator){
selenium.select("//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]","label=May");
selenium.doType(locator, "//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]");}
```

Where, `//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]` is the xpath of the drop down text field xpath.
and in selenium using command drop down but in desired text field I do not receive May in tht drop down text field.

Please help me, I will be grateful to you. If there is other code of fraction will run tell me the code as well with Selenium command, value and target. Thanks in advance.